# How to Copy all the data that is referenced in the Excel Formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple example here with an Excel file

Worksheet1 has some content like below

```
A1 = 2
A2 = 3
A3 = "=A1+A2"
```

Now, i want to copy the formula of A3 from Worksheet1 to Worksheet2.
When i do this, i should get the reference cell content (A1, A2) also to be copied automatically to Worksheet2 (some way to detect the reference content automatically)

Here, i don't want reference or linked cells, coz i might be doing it between different Workbooks

Answer (score 0):

Select Worksheet1, now press Ctrl and select Worksheet2 as well. go to A3, edit the formula and press enter. Now the formula sits in A3 on Worksheet2 as well. You can even select more sheets (up to ALL sheets) and do this across the sheets selected.